# Get Image dimension on click in Android using open cv and java?

Tags: java, android, python, c++, opencv

I am new in android development and I have to make a module for android app which automatically detects the exact dimensions of an object being photographed by the user's camera.

I have stumbled upon many examples and the best one is:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

I have read this complete post. But I think there must be also a way to get the object's size without a reference object.

could someone suggest any way to achieve this. Or some API which might be providing this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the pyimagesearch's way of calculating dimensions of the package. Right now this approach works fine for us. But the reference object concept is a bit non-satisfactory. But for now it's the only way I could think of.

please refer to this [URL](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) for the python solution to the problem.